# CUDA reduction using thrust inside kernel

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, host, reduction

I want to do parallel reduction, but inside my kernel with data in shared memory. Is this possible with thrust library ?
Something like

```
int sum = thrust::reduce(myIntArray, myIntArray+numberOfItems, (int) 0, thrust::max_element<int>());
```

But this doesn't work inside kernel. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thrust inside user written kernels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510715/thrust-inside-user-written-kernels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, thrust::reduce() is a host function that results in the execution of CUDA kernels if the data is on the GPU.

You would have to dig into the thrust source and find the `__device__` functions it uses for reduction. Those would be callable from your kernel. If the logic for reduction is contained in other `__global__` kernels, you'll have to piece it together manually in order to use it.