# thrust in cuda kernel

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have cuda 8.0 installed on my machine (Linux SL7 ) also, I have downloaded the thrust 1.8.1 and replace the existing thrust library with the new 1.8.1.

As far as I know starting from thrust 1.8 thrust is supported and can be used in the kernels. I quote from their website :

> Thrust 1.8.0 introduces support for algorithm invocation from CUDA
>   __device__ code, support for CUDA streams, and algorithm performance improvements. Users may now invoke Thrust algorithms from CUDA
>   __device__ code

however, when I build the application using the Nsight eclipse, it shows me this error:

> calling a __host__ function("thrust::sort") from a __global__
>   function("mykernel") is not allowed.

Please any advise?

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

__global__ void mykernel(int* a, int* b)
{

thrust::sort(a, a + 10);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[10] = { 0, 9, 7, 3, 1, 6, 4, 5, 2, 8 };
    int b[10];
    int *d_a, *d_c;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, 10 * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_c, 10 * sizeof(int));

    std::cout << "A\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << "  ";
    }

    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, 10 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    mykernel<<<1, 1> > >(d_a, d_c);
    cudaMemcpy(a, d_c, 10 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << "\nA\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << "  ";
    }

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thrust inside user written kernels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510715/thrust-inside-user-written-kernels)

Answer (score 8):

You are correct. Thrust 1.8 and newer do support algorithm calls within device code. However, to take advantage of this, you need to use the new [execution policies](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__execution__policies.html#ga98394c05ebaaac46c17cf0ec970695e0) to make the library work correctly in device code.

If you use the version of [sort](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__sorting.html#ga1099d781e06c43805be06a918f7b7499) which includes an execution policy like this:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int* a, int* b)
{
    thrust::sort(thrust::device, a, a + 10);
}
```

you should find the code compiles correctly.